# Drawing A Rosetta Shape

Tags: java, math, applet, drawing

I have to do the project with just a draw.oval function and draw.arc function. I really wish I could do it your way, however. This is what I have now, but Its still not lining up correctly. Any insight? Thanks!

```
//**********************************************************************
// Fish.Java    Louis Colucci
// Draws a rosetta
//**********************************************************************

import javax.swing.JApplet;

import java.awt.*;

public class Rosetta extends JApplet
{
    public void paint (Graphics page)
    {


        setBackground (Color.white);
        page.setColor (Color.black);


        //Draws the body

        page.drawOval(360, 360, 360,360);
        page.drawArc(360,180, 360,360,360,360);
        page.drawArc(360,540, 360,360,360,360);

        page.drawArc(525,435, 360,360,360,360);
        page.drawArc(525,285, 360,360,360,360);
        page.drawArc(195,435, 360,360,360,360);
        page.drawArc(195,285, 360,360,360,360);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like....

[image]

1. Stop using magic numbers, use actual know values at the time of rendering
2. Call `super.paint(...)`, this is very, very important, you will end up with graphics glitches if you don't.  In fact, use a `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method and do you custom painting there (but don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`)

...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Rosetta extends JApplet {

    public void paint(Graphics page) {

        super.paint(page);

        page.setColor(Color.black);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int roseWidth = Math.min(width / 2, height / 2);
        int roseHeight = roseWidth;

        int centerX = width / 2;
        int centerY = height / 2;

        int x = (width - roseWidth) / 2;
        int y = (height - roseHeight) / 2;

        page.drawRect(x, y, roseWidth, roseHeight);
        page.drawOval(x, y, roseWidth, roseHeight);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) page;
        float angle = 30f;
        AffineTransform t = g2d.getTransform();
        g2d.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(angle), centerX, centerY));
        angle = 60f;
        for (int index = 0; index < 6; index++) {
            g2d.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(angle), centerX, centerY));
            g2d.drawArc(x + (roseWidth / 2), y, roseWidth, roseHeight, 360, 360);
        }
        g2d.transform(t);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Rosetta extends JApplet

{

public void paint(Graphics page)

       {
              final int MID = 130;
              final int TOP = 75;

              page.drawArc(MID,TOP-76,150,150,210,121);
              page.drawArc(MID,TOP+76,150,150,30,120);
              page.drawArc(MID+65,TOP+35,150,150,90,120);
              page.drawArc(MID-65,TOP+35,150,150,330,120);
              page.drawArc(MID-65,TOP-35,150,150,270,120);
              page.drawArc(MID+65,TOP-35,150,150,150,121);

              page.setColor(Color.red);
              page.drawOval(MID-1,TOP,151,151);
              }         
}
```